# update primefaces or jsf view after ajax call on submit button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to update a primefaces form (wizard-first step) after an ajax command button request with no success. The command button that makes the actual ajax call is on a dialog. I would like after submitting the request to force my view to refresh.

The command button deletes a record from a datatable. It works fine, record is deleted but when dialog is hidden the datatable keeps displaying the deleted record. I would like to force it somehow to refresh. Any ideas? Could I do it from my backing bean `reviewManagerBean.deleteProtocol()` method?

Here is the code (my BackBean is viewScoped):

```xml
<h:form id="reviewManagerForm">
...     
<pe:masterDetail id="masterDetail" level="#{reviewManagerBean.currentLevel}" showBreadcrumb="false" selectLevelListener="#{reviewManagerBean.levelListener}" >
    <f:facet name="header" >
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="margin-top: 10px;" >
            <h:panelGroup styleClass="levelTitle ui-state-default ui-corner-all wizard-breadcrumbs#{reviewManagerBean.currentLevel eq 1 ? 'ui-state-hover' : ''}">
                <h:outputText value="1: Protocol picker"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            ...
            <p:messages id="mainMessagesPanel" showDetail="true" closable="true" />
        </h:panelGroup>         
    </f:facet>
    <pe:masterDetailLevel level="1">        
        <p:panel id="panel1" header="List of available protocols">                
            <p:dataTable id="protocolsDataTable" var="cRProtocol" rowKey="#{cRProtocol.revProtId}" value="#{reviewManagerBean.cRReviewProtocolList}"
                widgetVar="protocolsTable" 
                ...
                selection="#{reviewManagerBean.selectedReviewProtocol}" 
                selectionMode="single" >
                ...
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{reviewManagerBean.setSelectedRow}" />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{reviewManagerBean.unsetSelectedRow}"/>
                ...
                <p:column sortBy="#{cRProtocol.revProtTitle}" headerText="Title" style="width:200px;text-align:center;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{cRProtocol.revProtTitle}" />
                </p:column>
                ...
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="dlg5.show()"
                        update=":reviewManagerForm:deleteSingleProtocol"
                        disabled="#{reviewManagerBean.checkifProtocolIsOpen(cRProtocol)}"
                        ajax="true" process=":reviewManagerForm:deleteSingleProtocol" />                 
                </p:column>         
            </p:dataTable>                
        </p:panel>
    ...
    <p:dialog id="dialog-deleteprotocol" header="Delete Image Type" widgetVar="dlg5" dynamic="true"  modal="true" resizable="false">                
        <p:panelGrid id="deleteSingleProtocol">
        <p:row>
            <p:column>  
                <h:outputText value="Id:" style="font-weight:bold; padding-right:10px" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{reviewManagerBean.selectedReviewProtocol.revProtId}" />  
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        ...
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton id='protocolDelete' 
                    value='Delete'
                    action='#{reviewManagerBean.deleteProtocol()}'                                                          
                    ajax="true"
                    onclick="dlg5.hide()" icon="ui-icon-disk" 
                    update=":reviewManagerForm:protocolsDataTable"
                    process=":reviewManagerForm:deleteSingleProtocol" />  
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>              
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Your datatable should be re-rendered properly, you would have gotten an exception otherwise. This means that `#{reviewManagerBean.cRReviewProtocolList}` will get called again. Do you remove the item from that list? Otherwise, that should be the problem. You should refresh the list from `#{reviewManagerBean.deleteProtocol`.

Comment: you are right Magnilex ... my mind was stucked! thanks

Comment: Great. Posted this as an answer so you can accept it and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datatable should be re-rendered properly, you would have gotten an exception otherwise (something like *component with id :reviewManagerForm:protocolsDataTable could not be found*).

This means that `#{reviewManagerBean.cRReviewProtocolList}` will get called again. You need to remove the item from that list. This is appropriately done from `#{reviewManagerBean.deleteProtocol}`.

When `#{reviewManagerBean.cRReviewProtocolList}` is called after the removal, your datatable will get updated.